# LINQ, Lambda Expression Skip n records, while averaging the skipped records

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have an expression:

```
Records.OrderBy(o => o.TIME).Where((o, i) => i % interval == 0).ToList();
```

This does an alright job at taking a large list of data records and paring it down to a smaller list.  (interval is the number of records to skip).  The problem is, I want to average out some of the fields, and not just skip them.  I have no idea how to do this without making a huge loop.  It is worth noting that each data record has about 90 fields.  Ideas?

Edit: I want to be able to skip exactly every nth record, and average 2 specific fields (lat and long (stored as decimal)) and most likely leave the other 88 fields untouched.

Edit: I would like to go from

```
    timelat longmany other fields
    1   2   3   field1
    2   3   4   field1
    3   4   5   field1
    4   5   6   field1
    5   6   7   field1
    6   7   8   field1
    7   8   9   field1
    8   9   10  field1
    9   10  11  field1
    10  11  12  field1
    11  12  13  field1
    12  13  14  field1
```

To:

```
    timelat     long    other fields            
    3   3   4   field1
    6   6   7   field1
    9   9   10  field1
    12  12  13  field1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to group a large number of items into a smaller number of equally-sized "buckets", where for each bucket some fields are aggregated (e.g. averaged) and some are skipped (i.e. taken from the last item in the bucket).

Consider if you could do this:

```
Records
.ToBuckets(interval)
.Select(bucket => new Record {
     Time = bucket.Last().Time,
     Count = bucket.Count,
     Lat = bucket.Average(x => x.Lat), 
     Long = bucket.Average(x => x.Long),
     Other = bucket.First().Other
}
.ToList()
```

If this is what you want, all you need to do is create the ToBuckets method, which is a much simpler (and generic!) problem:

```
public static IEnumerable<IList<T>> ToBuckets<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int size)
{
    var bucket = new List<T>(size);
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        bucket.Add(item);
        if (bucket.Count == size) {
           yield return bucket;
           bucket = new List<T>(size); // or you can use the same one if you're careful
    }

    if (bucket.Count > 0) yield return bucket;
}
```

(The above is given as an extension method to support the example, but this can also be a regular method of course).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to include a given record in an average, you are going to have to touch that record.  *Something* is going to have to loop through all records, whether you are doing it explicitly or whether Linq is doing that behind the scenes.

A given Linq expression can only return one thing.

The Linq expression you currently have will return the filtered list.

You will need a second Linq expression (or your own loop) to average all of the records, e.g.

```
var avg = Records.Average(r => r.FieldToAverage);
```

I'm not sure what you meant by

> It is worth noting that each data record has about 90 fields

Do you somehow have to average the *fields* within a given record?  If so, what data type(s) are they?  Is there some existing method to enumerate all of those fields?  If not, you will need to explicitly access each field, or use reflection to enumerate (relevant) fields.

Comment: I think what I am looking for is an average with a group by every nth record.  The fields are a variety of datatypes (all known)

Comment: That's not very clear to me.  Can you add an example to your question?

Comment: I added example data.  I'm thinking more and more that I will have to mostly skip linq and use a giant loop.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to stick it in the Where clause. It'll be a bit ugly but something like this:

[EDIT: From your edit I now understand you wanted something a little different. This code has been edited accordingly].

```
decimal latSum = 0;
decimal longSum = 0;
int count = 0;

var recordList = Records
    .OrderBy(o => o.TIME)
    .Where((o, i) => {
        if (i % interval == 0)
        {
            // Modify the record in place (hope that's OK)
            o.Lat = (o.Lat + latSum) / (count + 1);
            o.Long = (o.Long + longSum) / (count + 1);
            latSum = longSum = count = 0;
            return true;
        }

        latSum += o.Lat;
        longSum += o.Long;
        count++;
        return false;
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This is indeed interesting, but I feel it's kind of abusing the Where. If we know we want to work with buckets of N-rows, why not explicitly add that as a step? I tried to do this in my answer.

Comment: Your answer is definitely more elegant than mine, but I think mine would be a bit faster. I'd probably go with my answer for a one-off, and yours for a generic function, or if I had to do the same thing many times.

Comment: @Avish: I had the same thought at first but then realized a custom loop will do exactly the same thing. Especially functional programmers would find the side effect introduced in the Where distasteful but it does avoid reiterating the list.

Comment: My version doesn't reiterate the list; it only reiterates each bucket to compute aggregates, and the difference should be negligible (N loops of 1 operation vs. 1 loop of N operations, all you're saving is the overhead of foreaching over an array).

Comment: It actually does reiterate the entire list, because of your invocations of Average. Anyway, I got curious, so I created a test application to compare our two solutions. So far, it looks like my solution is approximately 2 times faster. I've seen a range of 1.9 to 4, depending on configuration (interval and number of records).

Code is [here](https://github.com/royhaddad/LinqTest)